# Changing Text Input Traits with Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka library with Swift https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka, and since the form inputs are generated programmatically I cannot change the text input traits from xCode utilities area.

[image]

I am wondering how I can change the Text Input Traits such as Capitalization and Correction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can change these properties on the `textField` on the `cell`:

```
let textRow = TextRow() {
    $0.cell.textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
    $0.cell.textField.autocorrectionType = .default
}
```